# Pass Value To Text Box From Combo Box with button click MS ACCESS

Tags: ms-access, combobox, textbox

I am creating a form where i need to fill some specific address and some address will be typed manually. Specific address i used combo box and typed the valued in it. Then i created a button and put an event trigger on it to pass the value to the address text box. But whenever i click on the button i get an error message.

> Compile Error, Argument Not Optional

here is my simple code

```
Private Sub saveadd_Click()
    addr.Text = optp.Selected
End Sub
```

i have tried all the solutions but stuck on this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Private Sub saveadd_Click()
    addr.Value = optp.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Bundle of thanks Kostas k. You have saved me from a hectic situation. Finally a wonderful solution after two sleepless nights. Thankd buddy ❤️